# LWC : Events - When to use event.target.value & event.detail.value

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, javascript, lightning-events, lwc-wire-adapter

I am looking for the difference between event.target.value and event.detail.value.

It was mention that To communicate data to elements in the same shadow tree, use event.target and To communicate data to elements that aren’t in the same shadow tree, use event.detail.

Can anyone explain it with some example?

Answer (score 14):

You are talking about ***event reparenting***. Check this question - [event.getSource() alternative in LWC? (considering origin reparenting)](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/270252/event-getsource-alternative-in-lwc-considering-origin-reparenting).

Consider below components chain in LWC:

```
<c:parent>
    <c:child>
        <c:grandChild>
```

When event is fired by **grandChild**, you can access all the ***data-*** attributes and any other attributes directly in ***child*** component using [event.target or event.currectTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target), However in ***parent*** component, **event.target** will refer to **child** component because of event reparenting and so you if you want to send some data to parent component from grandChild, you should use [CustomEvent.detail](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent) for communicating the data within.

**Note**:
1. ***event.target or event.currentTarget*** will give you the reference of the element which fired the event and ***event.detail*** will give you the information of data in custom event
2. ***event.target or event.currentTarget*** is valid for both standard or custom event. ***event.detail*** is valid only for custom event. (in standard event, event.detail will return 1 always)

**added**

3. You may get values in ***event.detail*** for lightning base custom components as they seem to fire event with data in **detail** as shown in [this example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/kvFFBzTZo/3/edit)

Comment: I used `event.detail.value` with a standard event to get the text entered in the input element. Take a look at this [playground](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/kvFFBzTZo/1/edit)

Comment: @dibocor, thanks for sharing that, its actually because its lighting base component. You can check this [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/kvFFBzTZo/3/edit) where you will not get for native elements

Comment: @salesforce-sas can you link me that playground? I am not currently able to view it

Comment: @TristanBerger Its because playground is retired. You can refer to standard [record-edit-form](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-edit-form/documentation) in which all events like success will have event.detail

Comment: do you guys know if it's possible to console.log the event? given it's proxied, we see 'Proxy(sep.constructor) {}' instead of the object itself. This makes de debugging way harder

Answer (score 4):

CustomEvent's provide the detail field for it to avoid any conflict with other event properties.

while

> The target property of the Event interface is a reference to the
>   object that dispatched the event.

as per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target