# Understanding different events fired by LWC Components

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-dom, onclick, lightning-pill

When to use `event.target.value`, `event.detail.name` or `event.currentTarget.name` and what else.

### More Info

While building my LWC I ended up using all the three above event variables because in certain scenarios one worked, but the other did not.

#### event.target.value

I used this to handle a key change event on a textArea

```
handleKeyChange(event) {
    window.clearTimeout(this.delayTimeout);
    const searchKey = event.target.value;
    this.delayTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
        this.searchKey = searchKey;
    }, DELAY);
}
```

#### event.detail.name

I used this on `lightning-pill` remove action. I was able to get the name of the entity clicked using this. `event.currentTarget.name` also worked, but `event.target.value` did not.

```
async handlePillRemove(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const clickedItem = event.detail.name;
    await removeSelectedItem({ caseId: this.recordId, item: clickedItem });
}
```

#### event.currentTarget.name

I am using this to get which `lightning-pill` the user clicked on. After failing with all the above options, `currentTarget` worked for me. But I hate the hit and miss trial I did and wanted to learn more about how it all eventually works.

```
handlePillClick(event) {
    console.log(event.currentTarget.name + ' pill was clicked');
    console.log(event);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple rule to follow:

- If you want to use a variable listed under the title "Custom Events" at the bottom of the ["Documentation" tab of its documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-pill/documentation) (or generally in the context of a specific event), query it on the `event.detail`.
- If you want to use a variable listed under the ["Specification" tab of the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-pill/specification), query it on `event.currentTarget`/`event.target`.

E.g. the "value" of a lightning-input is available as event.currentTarget.value, because it's listed as a property of the element (under "Attributes" in the "Specification" tab).

However, there is a lot of redundancy. Salesforce itself sometimes holds the data already as a public property and then attaches it to the event. E.g. draftValues for datatables are available both on the target and on the detail. When Salesforce creates the detail, it just copies it over. Or think of the name property, which is very often available on the component, but only sometimes copied into the detail.

As for the exact property available, you should rely on the documentation, because documentation serves like a contract that requires the documenting party to continue to provide an interface (or warn us years ahead of changes).

But we can always have a peek ourselves too. We can set a breakpoint in our event handler, and look at the call stack e.g. Chrome DevTools provides. Standard events like onclick are more tricky to track to its source. But you often find Salesforce's LWC there, e.g. primitiveInputSimple LWC for lightning-input/onchange; or pill.js for the lightning-pill event onremove. Snooping around has the benefit you can see both what is set on the detail...

```javascript
const removeEvent = new CustomEvent('remove', {
    cancelable: true,
    detail: {
        name: this.name
    }
});
```

... and on the target...

```javascript
publicProps: {
    href: {
        config: 3
    },
    label: {
        config: 0
    },
    [...]
}
```

(Example from pills.js.)

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to read about [Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) on MDN. This is a web standard, not just in LWCs. It's helpful to understand how the various properties of event works. When an event is fired, certain properties are set. These will depend on the event.

## `event.target`

This is the element that **generated** the event. In LWC, if the event crosses a shadow boundary (see [Shadow DOM](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/create-dom.html)), the target will become the component where the shadow boundary was crossed. This protects the internal implementation of the component.

## `event.detail`

These are custom properties that are defined for that event. This is component specific, so you must check the documentation for that component. Standard events, like "onclick", don't have a detail property. Instead, you just check the MDN or other documentation for that event (e.g. [click event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/click_event)).

Here's how a component sets the detail property:

```
const event = new CustomEvent('myevent', { detail: { message: 'Hello World' } });
this.dispatchEvent(event);
```

In the `onmyevent` handler in the parent component, `console.log(event.detail.message)` will print "Hello World".

## `event.currentTarget`

This is the element that's **handling** the event, which is typically a parent of the target. For example:

```
<div onclick={handleClick}>
  <span>This is clickable text</span>
</div>
```

In this case, `handleClick` will have `event.target` set to the `span`, while `event.currentTarget` will be set to the `div`.

Once you understand the difference between these properties, it should be easier to deduce which property you're supposed to use.

Answer (score 0):

I find this answer to a similar question most helpful: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/285306/63755

But there are also traces of this type of question and conversation within the realm of Javascript more generically than just LWCs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10086427/9432048

What I personally do when I encounter a situation like this:

1. Consult the [Component Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/overview/components) for the component you're using.
2. If that fails for whatever reason, just log the event object and assess for yourself what you're going to need to use to get your component to work.